# XSLT to convert XML schema to HTML

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xsd

I've made an XML schema but I don't know if I need an XSL stylesheet to show it in HTML. Do I need one? If I do, has anyone got an example which I could see and learn how to make one for my XML schema?

Answer (score 3):

For an XSLT solution take a look at:

- **[XS3P](http://xml.fiforms.org/xs3p/)**
- **[XSDDoc](http://xframe.sourceforge.net/xsddoc/index.html)**, which produces JavaDoc-like documentation.

There are also a variety of tools that can produce W3C Schema documentation, such as:

- [oXygen](http://www.oxygenxml.com/xml_schema_documentation.html)
- [Stylus Studio](http://www.stylusstudio.com/xml_schema_doc_gen.html)
- [XML Schema Documenter](http://xsddoc.codeplex.com/)